# why the view not display on angular js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to display a view using angular js using module form .could you please tell me why it is not display my view  or page 
I share my code on this link 
http://goo.gl/ocBdQ5

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />
    <script src="lib/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="lib/angular-ui-router.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="js/firtdir/module.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="js/firtdir/router.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
       <script src="js/firtdir/controller/firstcontroller.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body >
     <div ng-app="firstApp">
         <div ui-view="app"></div>
     </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed the following issues and now your sample is working.

Demo: http://goo.gl/3eh5hz

## Issues Fixed

index.html >> Directory name is corrected as "firstdir" in url

Routes >> controller should be inside views as follows

```
$stateProvider.state('app', {
 url: '/app',
 views:{
  app: 
  {
        templateUrl: 'js/firstdir/templates/firstpage.html', 
        controller:"firstcont" 
  }
 }
});
```